# g++ error: ‘vec’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm trying to work with C++ STL vectors. Here is my program:

```
# include <iostream> 
# include <vector>

using namespace std; 

vector<int> vec; 

vec.push_back(10);
vec.push_back(5);
vec.push_back(1);

vector<int>::iterator itr1 = vec.begin();
vector<int>::iterator itr2 = vec.end();

for(vector<int>::iterator itr = itr1; itr != itr2; itr++){
    cout << *itr  << endl;  
}
```

I get the error `error: ‘vec’ does not name a type` on the lines `vec.push_back();`. I'm unable to see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You can't have statements such as `vec.push_back(10);` outside of functions.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Really? I'm was trying to brush up on my C++. I was following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltBdTiRgSaw. He seems to use it outside functions.

Comment: Yes, really. The video might show code snippets out of context for brevity (I haven't watched it though.)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks for helping out. I've been only working with scripting languages of late, forgot the whole business of the `main` method :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Statements such as `vec.push_back(42);` are only allowed inside of functions. For example,

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  using namespace std; 

  vector<int> vec; 

  vec.push_back(10);
  vec.push_back(5);
  vec.push_back(1);

  vector<int>::iterator itr1 = vec.begin();
  vector<int>::iterator itr2 = vec.end();

  for(vector<int>::iterator itr = itr1; itr != itr2; itr++){
    cout << *itr  << endl;  
  }

}
```